# How can I plot a file.dat in gnuplot maching points with lines?

Tags: function, plot, graph, 3d, gnuplot

My problem is when I plot the points of my file (x, y, sen(y)*cos(x)) (50x50 points from -6 to 6) and use with lines like that:

> splot 'C:\Users\pablo\Documents\Programs\Fortran 90\CUAT 2\Graph\plot.dat' u 1:2:3 w l

... gnuplot match with lines all points from the x axis (1,1 to 50,1) and then link the 50,1 with 1,2. That's result on a continuos line imposible to fill with pm3d. I tried to use dgrid3d 500,500, it's takes a bit to load but it ignores lost of points. I want to use "with lines" in a way that match points making squares (1,1 to 1,2 to 2,2 to 2,1 to 1,1...). I don't know why it works with:

> splot sen(y)*cos(x) w l

... but not with plot.dat

How can I match points with lines making squares?

Comment: You should post the datafile. Are you complaining with gnuplot standard? Did you leave a space between each block?

Comment: It was my problem, thanks!